# Azure error descriptions back to Access

Tags: azure, ms-access

I've received the error "connection is busy with results for another command" - when adding a record via an Access DB connected to a SQL Azure DB.  Searching this error didn't turn up anything relevant, but I figured out that this was caused by a key violation on the table.  It would appear that a useable error message is not being passed back from Azure to Access.  Can anyone suggest how to handle this situation (other than querying the table in advance) - i.e., get an appropriate error description from Azure?

Comment: any relevant error message or code snippets can help

Comment: The error message is in quotes above.  There no relevant code to post - it is simply an Access form with an Azure table as its data source; when adding a duplicate record, the very unhelpful message above pops up.  Would like to know if there is a way to get an error message that indicates the actual issue.